# Как в Ansible модулю set_facts передать путь до файла, который лежит на удалённом компьютере?

Tags: linux, windows, администрирование, ansible, ini

Есть `setup.ini`, который лежит в папке `TEMP` и из которого надо получить переменные. У меня не получается передать параметру `file` путь в виде переменной. Хардкорить не хочется, делал как написано [тут](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/plugins/lookup/ini.html).

```yaml
- name: Set some fact about Autodesk product
  when:
    - ansible_os_family == 'Windows'
    - ansible_env.PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE == 'AMD64'
  vars:
    autodesk_path_to_setup_ini_file: '{{ ansible_env.TMP }}\setup-{{ autodesk_product_directory }}.ini'
    autodesk_product_directory: autocad
  set_fact:
    autodesk_adlm_version_fact: "{{ lookup('ini', 'ADLM_VERSION section=SETUP file={{ autodesk_path_to_setup_ini_file }} encoding=utf-16') }}"
  delegate_to: "{{ inventory_hostname }}"
```

Ошибка:

```json
fatal: [10.10.10.178]: FAILED! => {
    "msg": "An unhandled exception occurred while running the lookup plugin 'ini'. Error was a <class 'ansible.errors.AnsibleParserError'>, original message: Invalid filename: 'None'"
}
```

`ansible 2.9.13`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я нашёл способ. Есть модуль для пошика под названием [psini](https://github.com/lipkau/PsIni), который превращает `ini` в объект. Дальше мы экспортируем в `json`, `json` пихаем в факт и всё начинает работать.

Вот как-то так:

```yaml
- name: Install PowerShell module PsIni 4 Windows
  when: ansible_os_family == 'Windows'
  become: yes
  become_method: runas
  become_flags: logon_type=new_credentials logon_flags=netcredentials_only
  win_psmodule:
    name: psini
    state: present
    allow_clobber: yes

- name: Get info from setup.ini
  when:
    - ansible_os_family == 'Windows'
    - ansible_env.PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE == 'AMD64'
  become: yes
  become_method: runas
  become_flags: logon_type=new_credentials logon_flags=netcredentials_only
  vars:
    current_version: 2020
    autodesk_product_directory: autocad
  win_shell: |
    Import-Module -Name PsIni
    # Т.к. тут пошик, то можно setup.ini не копировать, с сразу дёргать по сети.
    $AUTODESK_SETUP_INI_FILE_CONTENT = Get-ChildItem \\10.10.10.10\autodesk\{{ current_version }}\{{ autodesk_product_directory }}\setup.ini | Get-IniContent
    echo $AUTODESK_SETUP_INI_FILE_CONTENT | ConvertTo-Json -Compress
  register: autodesk_setup_ini_file_content
  changed_when: false

# https://gist.github.com/halberom/e276aed3e99ae7df143c
- set_fact:
    autodesk_setup_ini_file_content_to_json_fact: "{{ autodesk_setup_ini_file_content.stdout | from_json }}"

- set_fact:
    autodesk_product_version_fact: "{{ autodesk_setup_ini_file_content_to_json_fact.SETUP.ADLM_VERSION }}"
```